# JQuery hide and show functions not working for all sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was using 3 sliders, when I load first slider text 1 is showing
other two text are hide. like wise I was written remaining two sliders
but functions only working third sliders only every time I was running
slider 3 functions only working.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    <!--- slider 1   ---->  

    $("#slide1").load("/startup.php#Screenshots", function() {

        $(".arc111").show();
        $(".arc112").hide();
        $(".arc113").hide();
    });

    <!--- slider 2   ---->     

    $("#slide2").load("/startup.php#Screenshots/slide2", function() {

        $(".arc112").show();
        $(".arc111").hide();
        $(".arc113").hide();

    });

    <!--- slider 3   ---->  

    $("#slide3").load("/startup.php#Screenshots/slide3", function() {

        $(".arc113").show();
        $(".arc112").hide();
        $(".arc111").hide();

    });

});
</script>



<p class="arc111"> text1</p>
<p class="arc112"> text2</p>
<p class="arc113"> text3</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `$(document).ready` you are loading all the slides. ie it will load slide1, slide2 and slide3. so third slide will be visible every time. change your code to fire the load events of each slider. like -

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $(".arc111").show();
     $(".arc112").hide();
     $(".arc113").hide();

     $("#slide1").click(function() {
         $( "#slide1" ).load( "/startup.php", function() {
            $(".arc111").show();
            $(".arc112").hide();
            $(".arc113").hide();
       });
     });

    $("#slide2").click(function() {
       $( "#slide2" ).load( "/startup.php", function() {
            $(".arc112").show();
            $(".arc111").hide();
            $(".arc113").hide();
        });
    });

    $("#slide2").click(function() {
       $( "#slide3" ).load( "/startup.php", function() {
            $(".arc113").show();
            $(".arc112").hide();
            $(".arc111").hide();
       });
    });
});
```

**Edit**

I have checked the site which you mentioned in the comment. I think what you want to do is that when the user click on next and prev icons you want to display and hide corresponding div.

use the following code to do that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".arc111").hide();
    $(".arc112").hide();
    $(".arc113").hide();

    $('body').on('click', '.fp-next', function () {
      changeText();
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.fp-prev', function () {
      changeText();
    });

    function changeText(){
      $(".arc112").hide();
      $(".arc111").hide();
      $(".arc113").hide();
      switch ($(".fp-slidesContainer .active").prop("id")) {
          case "slide1":
              $(".arc111").show();
              break;
          case "slide2":
              $(".arc112").show();
              break;
          case "slide3":
              $(".arc113").show();
              break;
          default:
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: i have to change this you mentioned but now it comes 3 texts together

Comment: @ManojKumar : May be you didnot set the visibility at the time of load. I Have edited the code. Please check

Comment: Aneesh Sivaraman i was using your edited code now its working only first text

Comment: @ManojKumar : Actually I dont know what is happening in your side. Please post the code in a jsfiddle. So I can check it easily.

Comment: can you pls check @ visiting page http://www.beamon.com/testing/boots2_new/startup.php#Screenshots/ - when i change screenshot slider and show only their corresponding text... now when i change their slider it comes first text  only

Comment: dude thanks for your effort !!! now i have edit and change this code as you mentioned still not working !!!

Comment: yeah sure can you please check now

Comment: Please remove additional      });   After $(document).ready there is an additional closing .Please check the console.

Comment: yes i have changed still doesn't work can you please visit my site

Comment: dude its working thank you :) its working fine slide2 and slide3 but when i change the slide1 it will shows first text and second text

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: its working fine dude  thanks for your help !!! but its working only when i click and change the mobile navigation icon ...when i change the slider navigation its not working ...  slider navigation is available on under the text (3 dots)

Comment: You need to call the same function (changeText)  when clicking on the dots.. It is very difficult for me to debug your site.

Answer (score 1):

what i understand about your code is that at read time loaded page, it load #slide1, then #slide2, then #slide3...
Not sure what you want to do, but, maybe you would prefer to handle an event on div, and then load them.
so

```
$("#slide1").click(function() {
   $("#slide1").load(....
```